# GoogleAnalyticsR authentication in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, google-analytics-api

I can access my Google Analytics data using the ga_auth function with my account number. I can pull down the data and everything looks great. But, when I try to knit to a PDF, it tells me that:

> The default Google Cloud Project for GoogleAnalyticsR is intended for evaluation only, not production scripts

And it suggests that I use an authentication method gar_set_client.

I'm trying to create a pdf from my rmarkdown to easily share the information with coworkers. I've tried setting up a token like I did for Google Sheets. I've tried this in two ways:

1. authorize(client.id="my_id", client.secret="my_secret"). When I run this, I get a Error: redirect_uri_mismatch.
2. googleAuthR::gar_set_client("oauth file.json"). When I run this, it says that the path doesn't exist. I've checked that the file is in my working directory, so all I need is the filename here, right?

What am I missing? Also, please keep in mind that I'm a data analyst, so I don't know all the technical jargon of programmers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, fixed in following way:

1) Download `json` from page like https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/...

2) check if your `json` have  `client_secret`.
My previous `json` haven't such field.
Structure of correct file is shown below

```
{"installed":
    {"client_id":"XXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
     "project_id":"XXXX",
     "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
     "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
     "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
     "client_secret":"XXXX",
     "redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]}}
```

3) In code it looks like this, with your `json` path/name and email.

```
googleAuthR::gar_set_client('path/google_project.json')
gar_auth(email = 'mail@example.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a different JSON file, the client id you download from your created Google Cloud platform project. There is a guide including a video walk through on the [googleAnalyticsR setup section](https://code.markedmondson.me/googleAnalyticsR/articles/setup.html#professional-mode-your-own-google-project) of the website.

Then you would do something like this:

```r
googleAuthR::gar_set_client("client_json.json")
library(googleAnalyticsR)
ga_auth()
```

Comment: Yes, this is the json file I used. I tried it again and it still isn't working (as above). Any other ideas?

Comment: I guess you are trying to load the file from a working directory not what you expect. Try issuing list.files() and see if you can see the auth file there. The error message says it is not. Move the file to the right directory, or change the working directory via setwd()